# How to configure Windows 2012 Server to receive GIT pushes

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012-r2, git

I'm new on GIT, and I would like to configure a Windows 2012 Server to be a GIT repository (--bare) so the developers can clone and push updates to this server.
I can't find any documentation to learn how to configure SSH or other protocol on the server so I can do this... Can I get some help, please?

Comment: Good video tutorial for Bonobo Git Server: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3Dm2Z-hc1o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run actual git server software of some variety/flavor; it's not enough to just add SSH/HTTP functionality. Googling "windows 2012 git server" produces a plethora of results with different software stacks and how to install/configure them. You may want to do that, have a look through the results, and then try some things out to see what suits you best.

Comment: Thanks... Found this one: https://bonobogitserver.com/ looks simple to install.